# Issues in a binding library project, how to add libicucore.dylib and libstdc++.6.0.9?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I created a Bindins Library project, I used sharpie, I added the frameworks I needed in the .linkwith.cs.

But I also need libicucore.dylib and libstdc++.6.0.9 and I don't know how to add them.

I'm also not sure about other parameters like SmartLink and LinkerFlags.

This is in the .linkwith.cs file, but do I need to add something in the main project under Additional mtouch arguments"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the extra linker flags via `.linkwith.cs` file:

- LinkerFlags = "-lstdc++.6.0.9"
- LinkerFlags = "-licucore"

You can pass multiple linker flags:

- LinkerFlags = "-licucore -lstdc++.6.0.9"

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/ObjCRuntime.LinkWithAttribute.LinkerFlags/

Comment: That one would be the Mac's OS-X version, you would be looking for  `libicucore.tdb`, just like libstdc++ is a `.tbd` also (libstdc++.tdb) These changed names in Xcode 7.1(?) 7.2(?)

Comment: I think I was missing an other framework, so that's why I was still getting some errors. thanks.

Comment: Cool, great to hear you find the issue